# Pandas DataFrame constructor introduces NaN when including the index argument

Tags: python, pandas

I'm creating a pandas DataFrame object using the DataFrame constructor. My data is a dict of lists and categorical data Series objects. When I pass an index to the constructor, my categorical data series gets reset with NaN values. What's going on here? Thanks in advance!

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.Series(['a','b','c'],dtype="category")
b = pd.Series(['a','b','c'],dtype="object")
c = pd.Series(['a','b','cc'],dtype="object")

A = pd.DataFrame({'A':a,'B':[1,2,3]},index=["0","1","2"])
AA = pd.DataFrame({'A':a,'B':[1,2,3]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'A':b,'C':[4,5,6]})    

print("DF A:")
print(A)
print("\nDF A, without specifying an index in the constructor:")
print(AA)
print("\nDF B:")
print(B)
```

Comment: For others reading this, the documentation is explicit about this issue: "... Thus, a dict of Series plus a specific index will discard all data not matching up to the passed index. ..." From: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with categories vs. object, it has to do with index alignment.

You're getting NaNs in A because you're telling the constructor you want an index of three strings.  But `a` has an index of its own, consisting of the integers `[0, 1, 2]`.  Since that doesn't match the index you've said you want, the data doesn't align, and so you get a DataFrame with the index you said you wanted and the NaNs highlight that the data is missing.  By contrast, `B` is simply a list, and so there's no index to ignore, and accordingly it assumes the data is given in index-appropriate order.

This might be easier to see than to explain.  Regardless of dtype, if the indices don't match, you get NaN:

```
In [147]: pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.Series(list("abc"), dtype="category"),'B':[1,2,3]},
          index=["0","1","2"])
Out[147]: 
     A  B
0  NaN  1
1  NaN  2
2  NaN  3

In [148]: pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.Series(list("abc"), dtype="object"),'B':[1,2,3]},
          index=["0","1","2"])
Out[148]: 
     A  B
0  NaN  1
1  NaN  2
2  NaN  3
```

If you use a fully-matching index, it works:

```
In [149]: pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.Series(list("abc"), dtype="object"),'B':[1,2,3]},
          index=[0,1,2])
Out[149]: 
   A  B
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  c  3
```

And if you use a partially-matching index, you'll get values where the indices align and NaN where they don't:

```
In [150]: pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.Series(list("abc"), dtype="object"),'B':[1,2,3]},
          index=[0,1,10])
Out[150]: 
      A  B
0     a  1
1     b  2
10  NaN  3
```