# Setting indexes in pandas dataframe subclass

Tags: python, pandas, inheritance, dataframe, constructor

## What I want to do:

I am currently building a subclass of the `pandas` `DataFrame` using python 3.  One feature of the class is the user inputs their `data` as well as the names of columns to use to create a `MultiIndex` for the class at time of construction.  However, I am struggling for find a clean way of doing this.

## Failed Strategy #1

My first attempt looked something like the following where I try to construct the data and the index values before calling the `DataFrame` constructor:

```
class DFSubClass(pd.DataFrame):
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return DFSubClass

    def __init__(self, data=None, #other DataFrame parameters#,
                 col_for_multi_index = None):

        multi_index = CreateMultiIndex(data, col_for_multi_index)
        data_subset = RemoveIndexColumnsFromData(data, col_for_multi_index)

        super(DFSubClass,self).__init__(data = data_subset,
                                                 index = multi_index,
                                                 #other DataFrame parameters#)

        multi_index = ComputeMultiIndexFromColumns(data, col_for_multi_index)

        self = self.set_index(multi_index)
```

While I was able to makes something that I think works for `ComputeMultiIndexFromColumns()`:

```
def ComputeMultiIndexFromColumns(data = None, cols = None):
    index_values = [np.array(data[i]) for i in cols]
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(index_values, names=cols)
    return index
```

I couldn't figure out anything for `RemoveIndexColumnsFromData()` that would cleanly handle all of the different data types a `pandas` constructor can accept (i.e. `numpy arrays`, `dicts`, other `DataFrame`s).  Also, when the input was a `DataFrame`, I ran into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193186/pandas-dataframe-constructor-introduces-nan-when-including-the-index-argument) where the constructor returns all `NaN`s because the previous indexes don't match the new `index` values.

## Failed Strategy #2

At this point I decided to not reinvent the wheel and let the `pandas` package handle these problems by first calling the `DataFrame` constructor and then using the `set_index()` functionality to re-index my data:

```
class DFSubClass(pd.DataFrame):
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return DFSubClass

    def __init__(self, data=None, #other DataFrame parameters#,
                 col_for_multi_index = None):

        super(DFSubClass,self).__init__(data = data,
                                                 #other DataFrame parameters#)

        multi_index = ComputeMultiIndexFromColumns(data, col_for_multi_index)

        self = self.set_index(multi_index)
```

Holy infinite recursion batman!  It turns out the `set_index()` function calls the constructor in order to re-index the `DataFrame` meaning this function was just calling itself forever.

## Where I am now

I am feeling a bit stuck.  Going back to the first strategy seems like what I need to do, but I am a little hesitant to deal with all of the data types, particularly when `pandas` has solved this problem already.  If anyone knows how I can either 1) leverage functions already in `pandas` to do this cleanly or 2) an alternate strategy for solving this problem, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this ended up using `inplace=True`, so my final class definition looked like this.

```
class DFSubClass(pd.DataFrame):

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return DFSubClass

    def __init__(self, data=None, #other DataFrame parameters#,
                 col_for_multi_index = None):

        super(DFSubClass,self).__init__(data = data
                                        #, other DataFrame parameters#
                                        )

        self = self.set_index(col_for_multi_index, inplace = True)
```

The `inplace=True` prevents the constructor from being called and prevents the infinite recursion problem.

As a note, if the `data` object already has an index set, this will remove those columns from the data.  If instead you want those columns to be reset into the `DFSubClass`, you need to call `reset_index(inplace=True)` first.  However this has the downside that if the index was just the default index, `reset_index()` will give you a new column in the `DFSubClass` that is just the values from 0 to `DFSubClass.size[0]`.  The following code can prevent this from happening:

```
if not isinstance(self.index, pd.Int64Index): 
    self.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

However this will also prevent the call to `reset_index()` if the index is any of the classes that inherit from `Int64Index` like `DateTimeIndex`.  I haven't figured out a clean way around this, so currently I just have a function that checks if `self.index` is a `pd.Int64Index` but isn't any of the other classes that I know of that inherit from `pd.Int64Index` other than `pd.RangeIndex`.